# c for loop instead of an if statement

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

```
    distance = (u * t + (0.5 * (a * t * t)));
    printf("distance is ");
    printf("%0.5f\n", distance);
    printf("\n");


        if (distance >= height)
        {
            bounce = ((COR*COR)*height);
            printf("The bounce is ");
            printf("%0.5f\n", bounce);
        
            
            bounce_height = bounce;
            
            bounce = ((COR*COR)*bounce_height);
            printf("The bounce is ");
            printf("%0.5f", bounce);
            break;
            
        }
```

so basically I am making a program to get data values for a bouncing ball and I need to know the bounce heights which is calculated using COR (coefficient of restitution squared) * drop height. I need it to be able to loop through the program so after the first bounce height is calculated that value is then used in the equation to get the next one and so on. I am unsure on how to do this I started with an IF statement but that will only do as many calculations as i program in. Any help with this would be amazing thanks in advance. PS the values for COR and height are asked for from the user early in the program.

Comment: something along the lines of `while (bounce_height > 0) { /* ... print ... calculate new bounce_height ... */ }`

Comment: Tip: `(u + 0.5*a*t) * t` is numerically more stable than `u * t + (0.5 * (a * t * t))`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `while` loop and set a minimum heigth that stops the loop.

Something like:

```
#define MINIMUM_HEIGTH 0.1

float current_heigth = 2.0;
while (current_heigth > MINIMUM_HEIGTH)
{
    printf("Current heigth is %f\n", current_heigth);
    current_heigth = calculate_new_heigth_after_bounce...;
}
```

This will keep printing the heigth after each bounce until the heigth get below MINIMUM_HEIGTH